# Using a custom single product template for a specific product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to use a custom page for only one of the products in the woocommerce shop. I've been trying to apply the attached function but without success (which code is coming from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621049/woocommerce-multiple-single-product-templates-using-single-product-php-to-redire/43744022#43744022)).

I have a created a copy of the single-product.php file in my /woocommerce folder with some added code, but the single product view only shows the "standard" single-product-php and not my single-product-mock.php file.

And the product does have the product category "custom".

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'so_43621049_template_include', 10 );

function so_43621049_template_include( $template ) {
  if ( is_singular('product') && (has_term( 'custom', 'product_cat')) ) {
    $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/single-product-mock.php';
  } 
  retur
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43744022/3730754) that you are using works just perfectly. Your code is a bit incomplete too:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'custom_single_product_template_include', 50, 1 );
function custom_single_product_template_include( $template ) {
    if ( is_singular('product') && (has_term( 'custom', 'product_cat')) ) {
        $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/single-product-mock.php';
    } 
    return $template;
}
```

**So the problem could be related to:**

1. The location of that custom template, that should be in a 'woocommerce' folder inside your active **child theme** *(or inside your active theme)*.
2. Woocommerce support need to be enable for your theme.

Solutions:

1. be sure that inside your active child theme *(or active theme)* there is a "woocommerce" folder and add inside it your custom template `single-product-mock.php`
   *(but **not inside a "templates"** sub-folder)*
2. To check Woocommerce support is enabled:

   - Copy the default `single-product.php`
     template inside the "woocommerce" folder located in your active child theme *(or active theme)*
   - Go in backend Woocommerce > Status … and you will normally see in "templates" section (at the end of this page):
     With an active child-theme:
     [image]
     With an active theme:
     [image]
   - **If is not enable**, you should search and look to the related Woocommerce documentation.

One of those, should solve your issue.

Comment: This works! Amazing, thank you so much. @LoicTheAztec